# How to run background process in spring mvc framework

Tags: spring, web-applications

I have a web-application (using spring mvc framework). It makes the following:

1. Users upload a file to server.
2. Go to success page immediately.
3. Run a background process with that file.

So, how I can do this with spring mvc framework?
Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use asynchronous  marked  method. 
You got example here:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

and docs:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling

Answer (score 1):

You can use JobRunr (https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr) in your controller. You should add Maven dependency jobrunr-spring-boot-starter. Then you can run your code on separate thread:

```
@Inject
private JobScheduler jobScheduler;
...
jobScheduler.enqueue(() -> someJobService.executeSampleJob());
```

For more details you can check: https://www.baeldung.com/java-jobrunr-spring

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)