# Spring Boot Background Job

Tags: spring-boot, background, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot with Thymeleaf.

When user click on related button, it sends post requst and in the related controller method there is a function which takes 20 mins. This function does not return a value.

I just want to process this function in background. When application comes to the this function's line, it should send parameters to this function and keep processing without waiting a return.

What is the best practice for this case?

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

My config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SpringAsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer{

@Bean(name = "ocrThread-")
public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
}

@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(10);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
}

@Override
public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Service class

```
@Service
public class OcrService {

@Async
public String treadliOcr(List<String> liste, String kok) throws 
InterruptedException, IOException, TesseractException {


 .....

}
```

}

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/aktar", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String aktar(@RequestParam("belgeAdi") String belgeAdi,
                    @RequestParam("evrakTurId") String evrakTurId,
                    @RequestParam("kategoriId") String kategoriId,
                    @RequestParam("belgeTurId") String belgeTurId,
                    @RequestParam("firmaId") String firmaId,
                    @RequestParam("projeId") String projeId,
                    @RequestParam("aciklama") String aciklama) throws InterruptedException, IOException, TesseractException{

    Integer b = null;
    Integer p = null;
    String klasor = getInitYol();
    String belgeOnAd =  belgeAdi.substring(0, 14);
    BelgeIsimleri belgeIsimleri = new BelgeIsimleri();
    List<String> seciliListe = belgeIsimleri.seciliBelgeleriFiltrele(klasor, belgeOnAd);

    for(String s:seciliListe){

        File file = new File (getInitYol()+s);
        if(file.renameTo(new File("D:\\Done\\"+s))){
            file.delete();
            System.out.println(s+"yi sildi");
        }           


    }



    OcrService ocr = new OcrService();
    String result=ocr.treadliOcr(seciliListe,getInitYol());
    System.out.println("Ocr dan döndü");


    Integer et = Integer.valueOf(evrakTurId);
    Integer k = Integer.valueOf(kategoriId);
    if(null==belgeTurId || "".equals(belgeTurId)){

    }else{
        b = Integer.valueOf(belgeTurId);
    }

    Integer f = Integer.valueOf(firmaId);
    if(null==projeId || "".equals(projeId)){


    }else{
        p = Integer.valueOf(projeId);
    }

    belgeRepo.save(new BelgeEntity(et,k ,b , f ,p ,aciklama, result,belgeOnAd));


    return "redirect:/verigiris";
}
```

Comment: Maybe with `@Async`? Example here : https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: I have already checked this guide. The problem is that it doesnt go next line before that @Async method is done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run background process in spring mvc framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059340/how-to-run-background-process-in-spring-mvc-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring provides annotation support for asynchronous method execution via `@Async` and `@EnableAsync`: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: I have already checked this guide. The problem is that it doesnt go next line before that @Async method is done.

Comment: Did you added `@EnableAsync` annotation ?

Comment: I have added all needed anotations but it still waits return value.topic is updated with current values. It is returning string value now. but even it returns void it still wait for method for done.

Comment: You're invoking the service using the new operator! inject it instead using spring `Autowired`. Also you should rethink your logic, as described the function does not return a value, and this suitable for async methods, now you're forcing to return a value ?!! and it should not be String, it should be a `Future<String>`. check this out http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Comment: You mean i need to use @Inject instead of @Autowired?

Comment: You should use autowired to inject your service in the controller class! you don't have to use `new OcrService();`

Comment: Sorry for dummy answers. I am new in this environment. Many thanks for your help. I succeded what i want now.

Comment: You're welcome ;) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work